# What do you call the logic gates visual programming of PS4 Dreams?

Tags: playstation4

The PlayStation 4's Dreams app has a visual programming framework made up of sensors (detect touch, a person etc.), logic gates (AND, NOT, splitters etc.), wires, and action outputs (move somewhere, execute keyframe, teleport etc.). Through these flows energy which is usually a value between (presumably) 0.0 to 1.0. This in turn is used to create full games logic, movies and more.

Is there a name for this type of programming UI? I can think of a general "logic gates" programming or so, but maybe there's something more specific. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Looks like dataflow programming.

Comment: @user253751 I think that's another great answer, feel free to post as such.

Comment: And also to add, two related terms: Behavior Trees, and (Unreal) Blueprints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programming in a point&click interface is usually called "visual scripting". A system like this which uses nodes with connections is often called graph-based visual scripting.

In a more abstract sense, you could categorize this as a [declarative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) programming approach. The programmer declares that *this* value is derived from *that* value which is calculated from *those* values. But declarative programming is not necessarily visual programming.

Another visual scripting methodology is block-based visual scripting which you can see in tools like [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/). This visualization model is usually used for [imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) programming.

Answer (score 3):

This reminds me of LabVIEW. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LabVIEW) describes LabVIEW as both "graphical programming" (referring to how the code is entered and displayed using graphical blocks) and "dataflow programming" (referring to how the code is executed).